# Why is this Update/Select subquery wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Ok so I run this query to get a count, and this is correct:

```
mysql> select count(medias.fileRef) from medias where fileRef=20193621;
+-----------------------+
| count(medias.fileRef) |
+-----------------------+
| 135869 |
+-----------------------+
```

So then I run this to place that count into another table:

```
mysql> update files set refCount=(select count(medias.fileRef) 
       from medias where fileRef=20193621) where id=20193621;

Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 1
```

(note that medias.fileRef is an INT which contains files.id), and files.refCount should contain a total count of all medias rows pointing at that files.id:

Then I go check it, and its wrong.

```
mysql> select refcount from files where id=20193621;
+----------+
| refcount |
+----------+
| 127 |
+----------+
```

How can this possibly be? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use the [Show Warnings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html) syntax to see the warning, & do update the question with that information.

Comment: What is the datatype of refCount?

Comment: As mwasif suggests, it is `TINYINT` or `SMALLINT` for `files.refCount`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `files.refcount` column data type is [TINYINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html). Change it to INT or any other reasonable [numeric type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html).